# How to use htaccess to point to a different directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't really understand the coding in .htaccess and I need its function for a project of which I do not have enough time to to start learning it yet.

How can achieve this with Apache mod_rewrite:

- If user visits this site directory `mysite.com/u/user1/`, point to `mysite.com/u/default/`
- `mysite.com/u/user1/settings/` should be `mysite.com/u/default/settings/` and so on.

Comment: i dont know how to work with this 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|excluded1|excluded2)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!u/).+)$ u/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: pls also, something like mysite.com/u/user1/settings/?task=set&next=home should load mysite.com/u/default/settings/?task=set&next=home